# Logging Analytics events from functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

We have three mobile apps that connect to our firebase instance: a client facing app, and two admin/employee facing apps. We log a variety of events in each, but we have several categories of events that we'd like to log that are not client-facing or initiated, but we need to attribute to a user. For example, if a user places an order and their payment is denied, or if they place an order that our system automatically cancels for some reason. Is it possible to log these from a function? We know the user ID, so it would be easy for us to attribute the event to the correct user, but I don't see a way to do this from a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Analytics does not support direct logging of events from sources other than the mobile app.  However, you can:

1. [Export your Firebase data to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7030014?hl=en), making sure that your events have the ID of the user
2. Write backend code to log other events to another table in BigQuery, using the same ID
3. Write a query to join those tables on the common ID to get continuity among all those events

Essentially, you will need to corral all your data in BigQuery to make it possible to merge your data from both the frontend and backend.

Comment: Nice, we just started using BigQuery to build analytics dashboards, and I suspected that that was the correct answer, but before I went that route I thought I'd check.